# Excel formula to check if a cell contains "Y", if it does divide a cell by 2. If cell contains "N" then do a IFERROR VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formula to check if a cell contains "Y", if it does divide a cell by 2. If cell contains "N" then do a IFERROR VLOOKUP.

Having some trouble I can't wrap my mind around.

[image]

If a cell in the M column has a "Y" then cell J needs to be divided by 2. (A half day is half the price of a full day). The J cell does a vlookup to fetch a price. K is a total of days that L needs to be multiplied to gt a toal price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cell J2 contains a Vlookup that results in the value 200, and you want to change the value in cell J2 then you need to address THAT formula.

So, change J2 to

```
=if(M2="y",Vlookup(this,there,2,false)/2,Vlookup(this,there,2,false))
```

This will do the Vlookup and divide the result by 2 if M2 has a "y".

If, however, you want to create a calculation in another cell, then you can just do a simple IF statement

```
=if(M2="y",J2/2,J2)+whatever
```

... where "+whatever" is whatever you want to do with the price or halved price. So if you want to multiply the number of days with the price (halved or not, depending on the "y"), then you need

```
=if(M2="y",J2/2,J2)*K2
```

Comment: Here is what I have for J2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,$O$2:$Q$6,3,FALSE),"")

Comment: =IF(M2="y",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,$O$2:$Q$6,3,FALSE),"")/2,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,$O$2:$Q$6,3,FALSE),""))

Comment: Came up with this! Testing it now.

Comment: I think it's better to leave J2 as is and do the division in the total calculation in column L, as in my edited post.